# Angular/Laravel CORS

Tags: php, angular, laravel, cors

I'm creating a Laravel/Angular application and I'm trying to connect the two for my login implementation.

When I log in, I get a 200 ok response code from the network tab. In the console, I get the following.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/login' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
>   login.component.ts:26
>
> HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/login", ok: false, …}

I have created a middleware named Cors.php

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return $next($request)
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    }
```

This is registered in my Kernel like so

```
 protected $middleware = [
        \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class, 
    ];

protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'cors' => \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class, 
    ];
```

It's also called in my api.php routes file like so

```
Route::group([

    'middleware' => ['api', 'cors'],
    'prefix' => 'auth'

], function ($router) {

    Route::post('login', 'API\AuthController@login');
    Route::post('logout', 'API\AuthController@logout');
    Route::post('refresh', 'API\AuthController@refresh');
    Route::post('me', 'API\AuthController@me');

});
```

Any idea as to whats going on.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `Cors` middleware to `$middlewares` applies the Middleware globally in your application so there is no need to call the middleware via the `api.php`.

Also, you are missing the `->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers');`

> The Access-Control-Allow-Headers response header is used in response to a preflight request which includes the Access-Control-Request-Headers to indicate which HTTP headers can be used during the actual request.

Answer (score 0):

Change Your Code To :

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    return $next($request)
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, 
        OPTIONS')
        ->header('"Access-Control-Allow-Headers"', '*');
}
```

And

```
protected $middleware = [
    \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class, 
];

protected $routeMiddleware = [
 //do not add Cors here
];
```

And

```
Route::group([

'middleware' => ['api'],
'prefix' => 'auth'

], function ($router) {

   Route::post('login', 'API\AuthController@login');
   Route::post('logout', 'API\AuthController@logout');
   Route::post('refresh', 'API\AuthController@refresh');
   Route::post('me', 'API\AuthController@me');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

just change Cors.php like this :

```
        $response = $next($request);
    $response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');
    $response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', $request->header('Access-Control-Request-Headers'));
    $response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    return $response;
```